# what textbook you reccomend me for study PDE Applied to real world

Tags: partial-differential-equations, optimization, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm pretty interested in study partial differential equations applied, in my undergraduate I take a introductory course in PDE and now I'm going to applied to master in applied mathematics so
my questions is what textbook you reccomend me for study PDE Applied to real world.

Also I'm focus in optimization theory (My project degree was about local and global extrema).

Comment: Do you want to learn about the theory of PDE or about numerical methods for the solution of PDE or how to use engineering modeling tools like Comsol?

Comment: @BrianBorchers Engineering modeling

Comment: Are you interested in PDE-constrained optimization? That has been applied to many real-world engineering problems.

Comment: Yes, I am @MarkL.Stone

Answer (score 0):

Partial Differential Equations for Scientists and Engineers by Stanley Farlow. This is for learning PDE.

For solving PDEs, go for FENICS, which is a python software for solving PDEs using finite element analysis.
There are many good book recommendations for FENICS on the fenics website.

Comment: [NGSolve](https://docu.ngsolve.org/latest/i-tutorials/index.html) to solve PDEs in Python is pretty good too